# Replace statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

Im trying to build replace statements but I'm getting this error:

The replace function requires 3 argument(s).

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

SQl script:

```
     select ccc.*,
     replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(bbb.Text, 
     '[Change]',convert(varchar,CAST(coalesce(ccc.change,0) as decimal(10,2)))),
     '[CurrentAmount]','$'+convert(varchar,CAST(coalesce(ccc.currentamount,0) as money),1),
     '[Increase]',convert(varchar,CAST(coalesce(ccc.increase,0) as decimal(10,2))))+ '%',
     '[AmountIncrease]',convert(varchar,CAST(coalesce(ccc.amountincrease,0) as decimal(10,2))))+ '%',
     '[AmountDecrease]',convert(varchar,CAST(coalesce(ccc.amountdecrease,0) as decimal(10,2))))+ '%'
     ) Condition
     from CCCCheck ccc with (NOLOCK)
     inner join BBBCheck bbb with (NOLOCK)on...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ccc.*,
REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(bbb.Text,
                '[Change]', CONVERT(varchar, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.change, 0) AS decimal(10, 2)))),
            '[CurrentAmount]', '$' + CONVERT(varchar, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.currentamount, 0) AS money), 1)),
        '[Increase]', CONVERT(varchar, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.increase, 0) AS decimal(10, 2))) + '%'),
    '[AmountIncrease]', CONVERT(varchar, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.amountincrease, 0) AS decimal(10, 2))) + '%'),
'[AmountDecrease]', CONVERT(varchar, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.amountdecrease, 0) AS decimal(10, 2))) + '%')
as Condition FROM CCCCheck ccc WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma at the end of your last replace before the parenthesis:

```
 '[AmountDecrease]',convert(varchar,CAST(coalesce(ccc.amountdecrease,0) as decimal(10,2))))+ '%',
 ) Condition
```

Looks like you might also be missing a REPLACE in the middle near the Increase replacement:

```
SELECT  ccc.*
      , REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(bbb.Text, '[Change]', CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.change, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
                                ), '[CurrentAmount]', '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.currentamount, 0) AS MONEY), 1), '[Increase]', CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.increase, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
                        ) + '%', '[AmountIncrease]', CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.amountincrease, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
                ) + '%', '[AmountDecrease]', CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(COALESCE(ccc.amountdecrease, 0) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)))
            ) + '%'
        ) Condition
FROM    CCCCheck ccc WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: I need column AmountDecrease...

Comment: I removed comma. Still doesn't work

Comment: Vinnie, I still get the errors: “The replace function requires 3 argument(s).”

“Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.”

Comment: So? Start rebuilding the query step by step from the parts. We are not a "I am not willing to put any work into debugging syntax errors, plesae do my homework for me" service here.

Comment: I didn't change the syntax, I just aligned everything so that you could see where you were missing a command.

Answer (score 0):

There are three places like this: `)))) + '%'`
Move that last parenthesis over: `))) + '%')`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis, I think

```
 convert(varchar,
         CAST(coalesce(ccc.amountincrease,
                       0
                       ) as decimal(10,2)
             )
        ))+ '%'
```

the last parenthesis is an extra one.

It should become

```
convert(varchar,
         CAST(coalesce(ccc.amountincrease,
                       0
                       ) as decimal(10,2)
             )
        )+ '%'
```